# Remove Contents from ToC in thesis class

Tags: table-of-contents

I am currently using the thesis class as in

`\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}`

when I put the `tableofcontents` it creates a selfreference to it that I don't want.

I have tried using `\tableofcontents*` with no success. Any other ideas?

I've gotten the template from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which class exactly is this, can you add a link?

Comment: I would assume, that either `\let\addtocontents\relax` or `\let\addcontentsline\relax` just before `\tableofcontents` could be helpful

Comment: Any of those work. The first one prompts a lot of errors while the second one breaks the class style everywhere.

Comment: @gunbl4d3: I will look into it

Comment: Ok. it was an option buried inside the `Thesis.cls`. It had an entry stating `\addtotoc{Contents}`. Commenting it solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up `Thesis.cls`, find  line 326 which reads

```
\addtotoc{Contents}
```

Either remove this, or add a `%` at the beginning, i.e. `%\addtotoc{Contents}`.

Comment: Just found the same. TY.